# How to create Word Addin Pane scroll button

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, ms-word, word-addins

I'm creating my own Word addin, and I'd like to recreate the scroll effect Microsoft uses with these little arrow buttons on the top/bottom of their panes (like the Document Recovery panel below).  Any ideas?

[image: resize and scroll]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any other solutions, so I created this:
[PanelScrollControl](https://github.com/sorrell/PanelScrollControl)